# how can i pass the csp on this extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to develop a chrome extension for a website and for that i am trying to add jquary to the site.
but when I try to add the jquery library as cdn with dom, I get an error like this:

Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

I tried changes to the manifest file.I tried to create meta tag and edit cps with this tag.But I did not succeed...

Comment: Put the file in your extension directory and load it the same as your other scripts.

Comment: Having your content script add `<script>` tags to the page, instead of doing everything within the content script itself, is something you almost never need to do, so I'd appreciate an explanation of why you want to do that, so I can tailor my answer appropriately. AFAIK, you only ever need `<script>` tags to interact with JavaScript already present on the page.